# No color in xubuntu wallpaper

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, desktop-background

For some reason, my ubuntu wallpaper suddenly turned black and white.  If I try to change the desktop wallpaper image it always shows in black and white only (i.e. no color).  Where the heck can I change this strange behavior?

I'm running the xubuntu desktop (i.e. xfce) on an ubuntu 11.10 installation (switched to the xubuntu desktop after giving up on unity).

Comment: I am having the same problems with debian unstable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked in #xfce and the answer is to set the

```
saturation  = "1"
```

I bet yours is set to "0" like mine was.